# How to format this date/time correctly? (Moment.js)

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, momentjs, ecmascript-5

I need to convert the `startDate` and `endDate` in the following format:

```
2021-05-20T21:00:00Z
```

How can it be achieved by the fixing this logic? `startDate.format('YYYY-MM-DD')`

Comment: `moment().toISOString()`

Comment: Your question is asking for something that is completely different from what you write in the comments to the answer below. See [ask].

Comment: @HassanImam how can I set 00:00 exactly so it will start and end exactly in 12:00 at night?

Comment: You can use `string#replace` to format your output.

Answer (score 0):

You can format any date using the following syntax

```
moment('2021-05-20T21:00:00Z').format('YYYY-MM-DD H:M');
```

if you have the date in any variable then you can use the following syntax

```
moment(startDate).format('YYYY-MM-DD H:M')
moment(endDate).format('YYYY-MM-DD H:M')
```

If you need to play with timezones you can check the following library of moment.js

```
 moment-timezone-with-data.js
```

Then the syntax would be

```
 moment().tz("America/Los_Angeles").format();
```

Comment: My question was different I mean to get this 2021-05-20T21:00:00Z kind of startDate or endDate  as a formatted result

Comment: Please check if it works for you and I correctly understand your question